# Will a constraint be applied between two statements during a transaction?

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many, constraints, cascading-deletes

I have a configuration that a `thing` can have multiple properties and a `property` can belong to multiple things:

```
CREATE TABLE thing (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE property (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE thingproperty (
    thing integer NOT NULL,
    property integer NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE thingproperty
ADD CONSTRAINT tp_thing
FOREIGN KEY (thing) REFERENCES thing(id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE thingproperty
ADD CONSTRAINT tp_property
FOREIGN KEY (property) REFERENCES property(id)
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I'd like to ensure that a `property` can only exist if it belongs to at least one `thing`, and for this I wrote this transaction that removes things (and then also properties if necessary) but I don't know whether it's correct:

```
START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM thing ... ;
DELETE FROM property
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT property
  FROM thingproperty
);
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

So I basically trusted the engine that after the `DELETE FROM thing ...` query had run, it immediately applies the `tp_thing` constraint and removes the record(s) of `thingproperty` belonging to the deleted `thing`(s) before `DELETE FROM property ...` is executed.

Is this a safe way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default constraints are applied immediately after every command in a transaction. You can (in this case you do not want to) change this behaviour declaring a constraint as deferrable. Read more about deferrable constraints in [the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html)

> DEFERRABLE
>
> NOT DEFERRABLE
>
> This controls whether the constraint can be deferred. A constraint that is not deferrable will be checked immediately after every command. (...)